# Project Euler 27 - Quadratic Primes

Tags: python, primes, programming-challenge

[Project Euler problem 27](http://projecteuler.net/problem=27)

I decided to try simple brute force, and it worked surprisingly quickly.  How can this be optimized?

```
"""Considering quadratics of the form:
n^2 + an + b, where |a| < 1000 and |b| < 1000
Find the product of the coefficients, a and b, 
for the quadratic expression that produces 
the maximum number of primes for 
consecutive values of n, 
starting with n = 0."""

from timeit import default_timer as timer
import math
start = timer()

def longestPrimeQuadratic(alim, blim):

    def isPrime(k): # checks if a number is prime
        if k < 2: return False
        elif k == 2: return True
        elif k % 2 == 0: return False
        else: 
            for x in range(3, int(math.sqrt(k)+1), 2):
                if k % x == 0: return False

        return True 

    longest = [0, 0, 0] # length, a, b
    for a in range((alim * -1) + 1, alim):
        for b in range(2, blim):
            if isPrime(b):
                count = 0
                n = 0
                while isPrime((n**2) + (a*n) + b):
                    count += 1
                    n += 1

                if count > longest[0]:
                    longest = [count, a, b]

    return longest

ans = longestPrimeQuadratic(1000, 1000)

elapsed_time = (timer() - start) * 100 # s --> ms

print "Found %d and %d in %r ms." % (ans[1], ans[2], elapsed_time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mostly quite good, but has some issues.

- The required answer to the Project Euler problem is not the values of \$a\$ and \$b\$, but their product. You could output that value rather than requiring another computation.
- Your prime test could be speeded up by first calculating a table of primes, then only checking for divisibility against that.

  ```
  primes = [2, 3]

  def extend_primes(upto):
      """Pre-extend the table of known primes"""
      for candidate in range(primes[-1], upto + 1, 2):
          if is_prime(candidate):
              primes.append(candidate)

  def is_prime(x):
      """Check whether "x" is a prime number"""
      # Check for too small numbers
      if x < primes[0]:
          return False
      # Calculate the largest possible divisor
      max = int(math.sqrt(x))
      # First, check against known primes
      for prime in primes:
          if prime > max:
              return True
          if x % prime == 0:
              return False
      # Then, lazily extend the table of primes as far as necessary
      for candidate in range(prime[-1], max + 1, 2):
          if is_prime(candidate):
              primes.append(candidate)
              if x % candidate == 0:
                  return False
      return True
  ```

  Whether this actually improves performance would have to be properly benchmarked.
- Your `longest` is an list. Instead, you probably wanted to use a *tuple*:

  ```
  longest = (0, 0, 0)
  ...
  if count > longest[0]:
      longest = (count, a, b)
  ...
  _, a, b = longestQuadraticPrime(...)
  ```

  What is the difference? A list is a variable-length data structure where all entries should have the same type. In C, the rough equivalent would be an array. A tuple is a fixed-size data structure where each entry can have a different type. The C equivalent would be a struct.

  However, I think it would be actually better to use named variables instead of indices:

  ```
  longest_count = 0
  longest_a = None
  longest_b = None
  ...
  if count > longest_count
      longest_count = count
      longest_a = a
      longest_b = b
  ...
  return longest_a, longest_b
  ...
  a, b = longestQuadraticPrime(...)
  ```

  This is longer, but more readable.
- Your code takes some nice shortcuts but fails to explain why you can take these shortcuts.

  For example, you only test a \$b\$ if it's a prime. This follows from the \$n = 0\$ case where the expression can be reduced to \$b\$, which therefore has to be prime. This also allowed you to narrow the search space from \$(-1000, 1000)\$ to \$[2, 1000)\$. Just mention this in a comment instead of implying it.

  If we pre-calculate a prime table, we could also iterate through those known primes instead of testing each number again and again:

  ```
  extend_primes(blim)
  for b in primes:
      if b >= blim:
          break
      ...
  ```
- Your `n` and `count` variables are absolutely equivalent. Keep `n`, discard `count`.
- Stylistic issues:

  - Variables and functions etc. should use `snake_case`, not `camelCase` or some `quiteunreadablemess`. If possible, they should consist of proper words rather than abbreviations, except for very common abbreviations like *maximum* as *max*.

    - `alim` → `a_lim` or `a_max`
    - `isPrime` → `is_prime`
    - `longestPrimeQuadratic` → `longest_prime_quadratic` (although this name doesn't convey very well what this function is doing)
    - `ans` → `answer`, but returning a tuple and destructuring this is probably cleaner.
  - Don't use one-line conditionals like `if k < 2: return False`. Instead, use all the space you need to make it as readable as possible:

    ```
    if k < 2:
        return True
    ```
  - Put spaces around binary operators. `math.sqrt(k)+1` becomes `math.sqrt(k) + 1`
  - `alim * -1` would usually be written with an unary minus: `-alim`.

Answer (score 2):

@amon sums up all the points pretty well. Adding on that, a possible optimization would be to check if (a+b) is even after already checking if b is prime.
This can be justified by the fact that at `n = 1` the equation becomes:

> 1<sup>2</sup> + a(1) +b

which is:

> a+b+1

Thus for a+b+1 to be a prime, a+b has to certainly be even, or in other words, also check if:

```
if a+b % 2 == 0:
```

Another optimization would be to store the last highest found value of *n* for a set of values of *a* and *b.* :

```
if count > longest[0]:
    longest = [count, a, b]
    max_solution = n-1
```

Now on the next test case values of *a and b* you could first check if the equation gives out a  prime value for `n = max_solution` intead of starting from `n = 0`.